# jQuery plugin: I would like to be able to access the selector from the method called.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

This is a simple example. Here is the call to the method.

```
$('.className').somePlugin.someMethod(1);
```

My question is: How do I access $('.className') within the below method?

```
$.fn.somePlugin.someMethod = function(someNode) {

    enter code here

}
```

I would like to dynamically get the $('.className') object from within the method as illustrated above. Any idea if this is possible without having to do something like this:

```
$.somePlugin.someMethod('.className', 1);
```

Thnaks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use `this` keyword ?

Comment: how can i use `this` keyword to get the selector? `this` ends up returning the parent object `$.fn.somePlugin`. Lets say for example I would like to add some css to the selector used.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some mumblings about there being a selector attribute on the jQuery object. I've never tried it though. It goes like this...

```
$(this).selector
```

Take a look at jQuery end(). It may be of some use to you here.

http://api.jquery.com/end/

Comment: `$(this)` runs the parent method. How do I end up with the `$('.className')` from the function call?